# Assign an array to the 'name' attribute in an HTML form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I went through some code, and I found some code snippet as follows. Here I see, an array is assigned to *name* attributes like `name="item[]` and `name="item[{0}]"`. I think this is an array assigning to add, items values again and again. I am not sure about that since I have not been using this before. Is this an array assignment or how is it used?

This is the first part in which the form displays a field to add items.

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control item" name="item[]" required="required" placeholder=" Item Name">
```

The JavaScript code is there to add a new field to enter items once  Add Another Item button clicks

```html
<script type="text/html" id="addChild">
    <input type="text" class="form-control item" name="item[{0}]" required="required" placeholder="Item Name">
</script>
```

Once the button clicks this above section add a new field to add items.

Comment: What this does is store the values of the form (in this case item) in the form of array which can be accessed by server siide as an array (like PHP). You can print the POST global variable to check them out

Comment: Refer to my answer which is smiliar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564665/how-do-i-create-an-array-from-form-input/53568619#53568619

Comment: @DhavalChheda, Thank you for the help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first part of your code is as mentioned `item[]`. This array collects the data from the input one by one and arranges it in numerically indexed form. It is just in case of PHP the indexes are added as keys.

**For example:** If we select multiple items (such as item1 and item2) in the input, the `item[]` will take the values and arrange them as:

```
array(
    [0] => 'item1',
    [1] => 'item2'
)
```